# va_list can't get any type

Tags: c++, parameters, variadic-functions

I have a code like this

```
 #include "atlstr.h"

void DisplayMessage(CString pszFormat, ...)
{
    CString str;
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, pszFormat);
    str.Format(pszFormat, argList);
    va_end(argList);

    _tprintf(_T("%s"), str);
}

void main()
{           
    DisplayMessage("This should be right %.2f = 700.0", 700.0);

    //Stop to watch
    int i = 0;
    scanf_s("%d",i);
}
```

But what I got when I run the code is

```
This should be right 0.00 = 700.0
```

I read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb57fad8.aspx) and I got

> ...
> Notice that testit expects its second parameter to be either an int or
> a char*. ...

How can I fix this? The function str.Format can do it right so I know there must be a way - I have read the source code of the Format function but I still don't know how to fix it.
Thank for reading :)

Comment: You should use `scanf_s("%d", &i);` to read the value.  See also [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`CString::FormatV`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314334(v=vs.60).aspx) instead - it accepts `va_list` as the second argument. Passing `va_list` to the `CString::Format` is a bad idea, because it creates another `va_list` with `va_list` inside.

It is common to implement two methods: one with variadic number of arguments and another with `va_list`.